# Python: PyCharm show "shape" by "mouse over"

Tags: python, pycharm

When debugging manipulations of large np-arrays with PyCharm I have encountered the problem that there is no quick way to check the shape of the array as hoovering the mouse over a variable shows only the first and last three elements:[image]

Is there a way to show 500 x 1000 x 4 x 45 instead? Pressing ctrl+F1 and scrolling to the shape property becomes a bit tiresome after a while ...

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for the same features. So far, I found this solution:

1. in the debug view, open the console
2. click "Show Python Prompt"
3. in the prompt enter

   ```
   import numpy as np
   np.set_string_function(lambda a: str(a.shape), repr=False)
   ```